# Equinox transforms activator

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, xslt, equinox

I have a problem that I can't solve.
I'm learning about equinox transforms and I can't resolve this trouble, in my Activator I put this piece of code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("equinox.transformerType", "xslt"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
registration = context.registerService(URL.class.getName(), context.getBundle().getEntry("/transform.csv"), properties); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

But Eclipse tells me that the registerService method can't be used with that parameters (String, Url, Properties), it accepts only (String, Url, Dictionary).
The examples from [Equinox_Transforms](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Transforms#How_To_Run_The_Examples) use the same method that I use, but in those cases it works.

What's the problem?

I change the example code in my Activator with this:

```
Dictionary properties = new Hashtable();
properties.put("equinox.transformerType", "xslt");
registration = context.registerService(URL.class.getName(), context.getBundle().getEntry("/transform.csv"), properties);
```

Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

The compile error you are getting from Eclipse that registerService(String, Object, Dictionary) in the type BundleContext is not applicable for the arguments (String, URL, Properties) is correct.
This is because of generic in java. **java.util.Properties** Class extends Hashtable, which follows generic rule.
Now if you see the arguments expected by BundleContext.reregisterService()

```
ServiceRegistration<?> registerService(String clazz, Object service, Dictionary<String, ?> properties);
```

It is clearly mentioned that it is expecting 3rd argument as Dictionary<.String,?> .

So when you are using simple Properties it unable to identify the type at compile time for this 3rd argument.

So, you second approach is correct:

```
Dictionary properties = new Hashtable();
properties.put("equinox.transformerType", "xslt");
registration = context.registerService(URL.class.getName(),     
context.getBundle().getEntry("/transform.csv"), properties);
```

You can check this even by changing the Dictionary reference to

```
Dictionary<Object,Object> properties = new Hashtable();
```

It will again give you same the compile time *error*.

You can get more on generics [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

You can read more on Equinox Transform and sample example on [Equinox Transform revealed](http://eclipse-api-inside-story.blogspot.de/2014/09/equinox-transform-revealed.html).

Comment: Cleared one small doubt

Answer (score 0):

When you used a Properties object what was the import statement?
It looks like you might not be using java.util.Properties (a subclass of java.util.Dictionary). There are quite a few classes called Property.

Comment: I'm using java.util.Properties

Comment: Hmm...I was assuming the context object is a BundleContext?

Comment: Yes. yes. What I've done was just to copy all the code from equinox examples into my Activator. It's interesting to note that also the example give me an error when I run it, but not before.

Comment: THink you're going to have to post the whole activator class, including imports